# PhoneGap + iOS Prevent default scroll action begins from input text field

Tags: iphone, ios, html, webkit, cordova

I've faced up  with the following problem:

I have a scroll area which contains list of input text fields.

I use

```
ontouchmove = function(e){ e. preventDefault(); }
```

to prevent global scroll of the page. It works fine except cases when gesture begins from input field.

How can I prevent global scroll of the page when first touch traps to the input field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to capture the touchmove event using the addEventListener function so that the even doesn't "bubble".  Try this:

```
/* This code prevents users from dragging the page */
var preventDefaultScroll = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.scroll(0,0);
  return false;
};
document.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefaultScroll, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

[this](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494815/Preventing-Scrolling-on-iPhone-Phonegap-Applications) might help

the section "MORE SPECIALIZED SOLUTION" might be what you are looking for.